# math.log(x) returns unexpected results in Python

Tags: python, math, logarithm

I am attempting to do some basic dB calculations using Python. If I use either Excel or a scientific calculator:

```
20*log(0.1) = -20
```

in Python:

```
20*log(0.1) = -46.0517018599
```

to simplify further, Excel and Scientific calc:

```
log(0.1) = -1
```

Python:

```
log(0.1) = -2.30258509299
```

I start my script with

```
import math

log = math.log
```

Can someone explain why this is and how I can fix it?

Comment: Sidenote: you can `from math import log` and save yourself a line.

Comment: It always helps to read the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html. This is important especially when using a logarithm function since `log()` can mean either base 10 or base `e` depending on the programmer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`math.log` is actually `ln` (with a base of *e*).  To get the expected results, use `math.log(0.1, 10)` or `math.log10(0.1)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `math.log10()`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That is true.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it certainly solved my issue and now its been layed out makes me feel a bit stupid as i was actually close to this answer from reading the documentation but simply didn't implement it correctly!! however I now simply start my code with import math
log = math.log10 instead of doing it in the equation as x, log(x) is derived from a simple division using variables causing additional complication and required me to learn/use the float function. so now looks somthing like this >>> rxcalc_dst = pntsrc_spl + 20 * log(float(pntsrc_dst) / float(pntrx_dst)) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the base 10 logarithm, you have to use `math.log10(0.1)`

Documentation is [HERE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html)

Fortran, C, C++, Java, tcl and many others they all use log as base-n logarithm (natural logarithm)